# A matrix being "diagonal with a $c$-column border", what does it mean?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, svd

[image]

The matrix in the middle of the beginning part, i.e.,

$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{diag}(s) & L \\
0 & K
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In the context, $L$ is a $r$ by $c$ matrix. **What is the meaning of $Q$ " is diagonal with a c-column border"?** It seems it means the left part $\operatorname{diag}(s)$ is diagonal and meanwhile the right part$\begin{bmatrix} L\\ K\end{bmatrix}$ is of $c$ nonzero columns. 
In the context the author call $Q$ a "c-bordered diagonal matrix".

But **is this formally defined in some linear algebra books? Or any reference?**